# Getting value of a apache's env var in servlet runtime

Tags: tomcat, servlets, apache2

I'm busy with apache2 with modJK mapping tomcat webapp.

Webapp should be accessed by many virtualhost servernames / serveraliases.
like

```
serverName a.domain.com 
serverAlias aa.domain.com
serverAlias aaa.domain.com
```

another vhost file:

```
serverName b.domain.com
```

every server names beginning by "a" should display the same thing

so doing a setEnv SERVER_A in may config file should be a good way, 
but I can't remenber how to get this environment var from the servlet code.

getcontext ? getconfig ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the value of an environment variable from a Java program, you must use [`System.getenv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28java.lang.String%29). It has nothing to do with the servlet API, and is of course global to the JVM.